# Mustache js order by

Tags: javascript, mustache

I know that `Mustache` is a "logic less" template scripting but probably what I'm looking for exist...

Imagine to have a model like this:

```
var users = [{
    {name: "Lorem", isOk: false},
    {name: "Ipsum", isOk: true},
    {name: "Dolor", isOk: false},
    {name: "Sit", isOk: false},
    {name: "Amet", isOk: true}
}];
```

When I create the template for users:

```
{{#users}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/users}}
```

It render everything in the model order.

Is there a chance to load first the `isOk: true` and after them the others?

I tried with:

```
{{#users}}
    {{#isOk}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    {{/isOk}}
    {{^isOk}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    {{/isOk}}
{{/users}}
```

But nothing change...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{{#users}}` wraps the whole list so the contents is repeated for each element.
You'd have to have to iterate twice over the list in order to split it like this.

```
{{#users}}
    {{#isOk}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    {{/isOk}}
{{/users}}
{{#users}}
    {{^isOk}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    {{/isOk}}
{{/users}}
```

Of course you could separate the list before you run over it twice:

```
// in js, divide in good & bad, join afterwards
var goodUsers = [], 
    badUsers = [],
    sortedUsers = [];
users.forEach(function(user) {
  if (user.isOk) {
    goodUsers.push(user);
  } else {
    badUsers.push(user);
  }
});
sortedUsers = goodUsers.concat(badUsers);
```

This way you'd only have to use your code once, but operate on the sorted list:

```
{{#sortedUsers}}
    <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/sortedUsers}}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to reduces the messy repetitions.